# Parent component removed when child routing happens in angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-router

i am working on a child route in my app like below. [image]

In this constant section should always be there even when child route happens. code sample i have produced here. When i click on a page, the constant section gets removed. How do i make in available always, i need the same folder structure. I don't want to move the `<app-constant></app-constant>` the app html file.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-childrouting-issue?file=index.html

Comment: You need to move the constant section higher up in hierachy. For example you could pull out teh app-constant to the app.component.html (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-childrouting-issue-qwrtjm?file=app/app.component.html)

Comment: I dont wanna do that. What is the issue with this way of implementation. Is should work right. There is a need i want to do this way.

Comment: When you route to 'page1' you are actually not using the Default Component at all anymore, rather you are navigating to 'Page1Component' directly. The 'page1' and 'page2' routes aren't actually child routes to the DefaultComponent.

Comment: Can you guide me as to how to make page1 and page2 child to DefaultComponent so that constant section is always present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created here three routes on the same level, so there are no child routes in fact. Your forChild(routes) is just a way of importing routes from other modules.

This is how you create child routes

```
  { path: ''      ,
    component:  DefaultComponent,
    children: [
       { path: 'page1', component: Page1Component},
       { path: 'page2', component: Page2Component}
    ]
  },
```

Your current router-outlet is good for the parent level,
You'll need a second router-outlet inside DefaultComponent

```
<app-constant></app-constant>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-landing></app-landing>
```

Comment: Here is the changed stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4-childrouting-issue-opzz3e?file=app/sub-module/landing/landing.component.html

Comment: Got your point. my childroute was never created. I was just using the syntax. If i have to use the forChild syntax how would the code look like?

Comment: @Hacker the snippet shared here is the base of it. See shadowlauch’s link, he integrated.